# php операторы, проблемка

Tags: php, операторы

Привет, столкнулся с проблемой, у меня сделано чтоб нельзя было отправлять форму где money < 1 и >1, надо сделать так что бы можно было отправлять форму только с целыми числами, т.е 0.1 и 0.1.0 и т.д нельзя было, прилагаю код моего запрета на <1 и >1, заранее спасибо!

```
 if($number > 3 || $money < 1 || $money > 1) return response()->json(['msg' => 'Nice try bro :(', 'status' => 'error']);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Запись

```
$money < 1 || $money > 1
```

эквивалента

```
$money != 1
```

Comment: я понимаю, мне надо сделать функцию которая блокировала бы числа 0.2, 1.2, 2.2 и так до 5 но разрешала 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Может просто привести к целому числу intval($money) ?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что вам нужно:

```
if(!is_int($money)) {
   return response()->json(['msg' => 'Nice try bro :(', 'status' => 'error']);
}
```

А если вам нужны только цифры 1,2,3,4,5 , тогда:

```
if(!is_int($money) && $money < 0 && $money > 6) {
  return response()->json(['msg' => 'Nice try bro :(', 'status' => 'error']);
}
```

Функция вернет ваш `return response()->json(['msg' => 'Nice try bro :(', 'status' => 'error']` если числа не целые

Answer (score 0):

если чисто числа то можно как-то так...

```
if(is_int($money)) //...
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-int.php

Answer (score -1):

Сравнивайте число с его округленным значением. Если они равны - значит целое